# Magento 2 : Create custom sticky admin system messages

Tags: magento2, global-messages

**I need to create custom sticky admin system messages.**

> Here is my code, But not working

```
class StickyMessages implements \Magento\Framework\Notification\MessageInterface
{
  public function getIdentity() {
   echo 'testing';
  }

  public function isDisplayed() {
    // write code to decide if this message should be shown or not
    // return true to show it, false otherwise

    echo 'testing';
  }

  public function getText() {
    // output a static text or dynamically generate one
  }

  public function getSeverity() {
    // if you return self::SEVERITY_MAJOR the sticky box on top will be empty
    // if you return self::SEVERITY_CRITICAL the sticky box will always show your text
    return self::SEVERITY_CRITICAL;
  }
}
```

[image]

I am getting admin to distort on loading

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y9AX.png)

[image]

I want to show an open message on top. So that when we login then simply show the mesaage

[image]

Comment: can you update your di.xml and Message file in question ?

Comment: The code is working but needs to show my own message. no need to open the dropdown. Please check the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write text in getText() function. Update your code like below way :

```
class StickyMessages implements \Magento\Framework\Notification\MessageInterface
{
  public function getIdentity() {
   return 'testing';
  }

  public function isDisplayed() {
    // write code to decide if this message should be shown or not
    // return true to show it, false otherwise
    return true;

  }

  public function getText() {
    // output a static text or dynamically generate one
    return 'testing';
  }

  public function getSeverity() {
    // if you return self::SEVERITY_MAJOR the sticky box on top will be empty
    // if you return self::SEVERITY_CRITICAL the sticky box will always show your text
    return self::SEVERITY_CRITICAL;
  }
}
```

**EDIT :**

You need to call model in di.xml file :

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Notification\MessageList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="messages" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="indexer_invalid_message" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\StickyMessages</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

> Reference : vendor/magento/module-indexer/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

Comment: Need to call the model?. I haven't call it

Comment: Not working. Can you please check

Comment: Yes. You need to call model in di.xml file.

Comment: Please screenshot images in comment

Comment: Can you please check?

Comment: I tested my answer. It's display perfect. Can you pls flush cache and check code properly?

Comment: Now, It's display perfect or?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101622/discussion-between-shiwani-and-rohan-hapani).

Comment: Check the chat messages.

Comment: okay Am checking

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to create “di.xml” file at App\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\adminhtml with the below code.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="Magento\Framework\Notification\MessageList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="messages" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="AdminQuoteMessages" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Extension\Model\Admin\Quote\Messages</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Once the file is created, you need to create another file at App\code\Vendor\Extension\Model\Admin\Quote\ with the below code and name it as “Messages.php”.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Extension\Model\Admin\Quote;

use Magento\Security\Model\ResourceModel\AdminSessionInfo\Collection;
use Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Notification\MessageInterface;

class Messages implements MessageInterface
{

    protected $backendUrl;
    private $adminSessionInfoCollection;
    protected $authSession;

    public function __construct(
        Collection $adminSessionInfoCollection,
        UrlInterface $backendUrl,
                                Session $authSession
    ) {
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
        $this->backendUrl = $backendUrl;
        $this->adminSessionInfoCollection = $adminSessionInfoCollection;
    }

    public function getText()
    {
        $message = __('Admin notification Add Successfully.');
        return $message;
    }
    public function getIdentity()
    {
        return md5('VENDOR_EXTENSION' . $this->authSession->getUser()->getLogdate());
    }
    public function isDisplayed()
    {
        return true;
    }
                public function getSeverity()
                {
                // From here you can change notification message type.
        return \Magento\Framework\Notification\MessageInterface::SEVERITY_CRITICAL;
    }
}
```

If you more refer [link](https://magecomp.com/blog/add-custom-admin-notifications-in-magento-2/) and [How to Add Multiple Admin Notification Messages in Magento 2](https://magecomp.com/blog/add-multiple-admin-notification-messages-in-magento-2/)

Thank You...